# arithmetic functions with $ 1/ \phi(n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

i have to find a function $f(n)$ such that
$$1/\phi(n)= \sum_{d\mid n} \frac{1}{d} f(\frac{n}{d}). $$

However, we know that :
 $$  \phi(n)= \mu* \operatorname{Id}(n) $$
$$ \phi(n)= \sum_{d\mid n}\frac{n}{d}\mu(d) $$
I have a feeling i need to use these equations but not sure how.

Answer (score 3):

Define $g(n)=nf(n)$ then:

$$n/\phi(n)=\sum_{d\mid n} g\left(\frac nd\right)=\sum_{d\mid n} g(d)$$

What is $g(n)$?

Comment: it means that $$ \frac{n * f(n)}{d} = n f(n) ?$$ so that means f(n)= 1(n)=1 so g(n)=n?  Im sorry i dont see how that helps @Thomas Andrews

Comment: That response indicates that you don't understand the question. There is no way that $nf(n)$ depends on $d$. It means that $nf(n)=(\mu * n\phi)(n)$.

Comment: you are right, i dont understand. How do we know this ? and how does this help get our answer?

Comment: Ah, I had a typo in my answer - I had $n\phi(n)$ when it should have been $n/\phi(n)$.

Comment: so is g(n)= n/f(n) too?

Comment: No, $g(n)=nf(n)$.

Comment: but how does that help us? i dont understand. Im sorry.

Comment: But let me re-iterate, the expression: $$\frac{n * f(n)}{d} = n f(n)$$ indicates you are missing something fundamental about what $d$ is. It is not a single value, but rather just a placehold.

Comment: Well, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Completing [Thomas Andrews](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/7933/thomas-andrews)'s answer.
$$
\frac{n}{\phi(n)} = \sum_{d|n}\frac{n}{d}f\left(\frac n d \right)
=\sum_{d|n}d \, f(d). \qquad (1)
$$
By looking up the inversion table [on this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Other_formulae_involving_.CF.86) (the 9th equation from the top of the section):
$$
d \, f(d) = \frac{ \mu^2(d) }{ \phi(d) }.
$$
The proof can be found on pages 8-10 in [Dineva](http://www.mtholyoke.edu/~robinson/reu/reu05/rdineva1.pdf).

So
$$
f(n) = \frac{ \mu^2(n) }{ n \, \phi(n) }.
$$

---

Edit. No cheating solution under [Thomas Andrews](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/7933/thomas-andrews)'s instruction.

Inverting (1), we get

$$
n f(n) = \sum_{d|n} \frac{d}{\phi(d)} \mu\left( \frac{n}{d} \right).
$$

This function is multiplicative since it is the Dirichlet convolution of two multiplicative functions.  Thus we only have to compute its value of a prime power
$$
\begin{aligned}
1 f(1) &= 1, \\
p f(p) &= 1 \cdot (-1) + \frac{1}{1-1/p} 1 = \frac{1}{p-1} = \frac{1}{\phi(p)}, \\
p^e f(p^e) &= \frac{1}{1-1/p} \cdot (-1) + \frac{1}{1-1/p} 1 = 0. \qquad (e \ge 2)
\end{aligned}
$$
So
$$
p^e f(p^e) = \frac{ \mu^2(p^e) } { \phi(p^e) }.
$$
Multiplying all prime factors, we get
$$
n f(n) = \frac{ \mu^2(n) } { \phi(n) }.
$$

---

Thanks again to [J.M.](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/293220/j-m) for the interesting question, and [Thomas Andrews](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/7933/thomas-andrews)'s patience.

Happy thanksgiving. :-)

Comment: Well, using an inversion table seems like cheating. $$nf(n)=\sum_{d\mid n} \frac{d}{\phi(d)}\mu(n/d)$$ so $$f(n)=\sum_{d\mid n} \frac{1}{\phi(d)}\frac{\mu(n/d)}{n/d}$$ Compute this for $n$ a power of a prime (since everything is multiplicative.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews. Very nice :-). Sorry for being lazy today. Thanks for teaching me this! I appreciate it.

Comment: thank you very much @ThomasAndrews